# Determine whether free(ptr) will fail

Tags: c, free

Because of some memory errors that I suppose to make in my code, `free(ptr)` fails for only one input among many others. One of the error messages that I have encountered is:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
pspmxm: malloc.c:3551: munmap_chunk: Assertion `ret == 0' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6f9d475 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

The program receives SIGABRT and ends. I wonder whether there exists a function (e.g., `will_fail_free(ptr)`) that informs the `free(ptr)` will fail so that depending on the return value of `will_fail_free(ptr)`, `free(ptr)` is not called.

I want to solve this problem with minimal change in code.

I use `gcc` for development purposes and `mpixlc_r` for parallel runs.

Comment: in order to see if the function would fail or not, one should invoke that function :)) looks similar to halting problem

Comment: You should probably rather rethink/refactor your memory allocation strategy.

Comment: First, fix the memory errors. Second, `int will_free_fail(void *ptr) {return 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using malloc/calloc etc then you can write a custom function like custom_malloc and in it call the actual malloc/calloc, store the returned pointer in a global array of pointers.

Similarly write a function will_fail_free() and just check the passed value is one of present in the global array of pointers. It's simple.

Comment: Dear @AgA, I have checked that value of the pointer returned from `malloc()` is same as value of the pointer that is passed to `free()`. It does not change.